# Got "malformed database schema" while open .svn/wc.db Using Python2.6.6

Tags: python, svn, sqlite

I'm attempt to get the revision of my work copy (subversion) using Python.
My Python is 2.6.6, and this is my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("wc.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
record = cursor.execute("SELECT revision FROM NODES LIMIT 1")
print record
```

After run, i got:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_revision.py", line 5, in <module>
  record = cursor.execute("SELECT revision FROM NODES LIMIT 1")
sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (nodes_update_checksum_trigger) - near "OLD": syntax error
```

Is that means the version of sqlite3 of Python 2.6.6 too old? I looked:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.4.1'
>>>
```

Comment: Check the `nodes_update_checksum_trigger` trigger (ex. by opening it with the `sqlite` command line program and running `.schema)`; see if your sqlite version supports everything it needs.

Comment: `version` is the module version. Show `sqlite3.sqlite_version`.

Comment: thanks. sqlite3.sqlite_version is 3.5.9, should i upgrade my sqlite of python?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you are correct: I think it means that the version of SQLite3 which wrote the database file was newer than the version with which you're trying to read it.

I encountered the same problem when reading Chrome/Chromium "Local Storage" from Python. My copy of Python (version 3.5.2) could read the localstorage file if it was written by Chrome or Chromium version 55 or earlier, but not if it was written by Chromium version 57, and the error I got was the same as the one you got: "malformed database schema"